# Is Bamboo will support AWS SAM or AWS CDK on Pipeline creation

Tags: bamboo, aws-cdk, aws-sam

I am having one doubt on Bamboo while creating pipeline it will shows only AWS Cloudformation.  Is it will support AWS SAM template or AWS CDK ?

If possible can anyone provide some example links.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you want to accomplish. And what you have tried/done so far?

Comment: All we just need is npm plugin to run tasks which perform `cdk deploy`

Comment: _"All we just need is npm plugin to run tasks which perform cdk deploy"_   Oh.

Answer (score 0):

from the comment:

> All we just need is npm plugin to run tasks which perform cdk deploy

NPM already has something for this:
Open your project's package.json and add a new scripts array item:

```
"scripts": {
  "test-error": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  // change distFolder to wherever you want to run cdk deploy in, or omit
  "cdk-deploy": "cd distFolder && cdk deploy && exit 0",
},
```

Then in a prompt, in the same folder as that package.json,  run

$ npm run cdk-deploy

more info here : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script